# Did I run create-react-app correctly to test?

Tags: testing, jestjs, create-react-app

I'm trying create-react-app for testing but can't get it to work.

```
npx create-react-app tester
cd tester
yarn
yarn test
```

OUTPUT:

```
yarn run v1.13.0
$ react-scripts test
Done in 0.59s.
terry@terry-sharewalker:~/myProjects/tester$
```

I thought I read that CRA starts in "watch mode", but it just jumps back to my cursor. Isn't is supposed to run something?  I see a test in the src/ folder called App.test.js. But is it running? How can I test that the test is running?

EDIT -- HERE'S MY ENVIRONMENT INFO:

npx create-react-app testing --info
npx: installed 63 in 11.717s

Environment Info:

System:
    OS: Linux 4.15 Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
    CPU: x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210M CPU @ 2.60GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 10.15.3 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.13.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.9.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/npm
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 68.0.3440.106
    Firefox: 64.0
  npmPackages:
    react: Not Found
    react-dom: Not Found
    react-scripts: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    create-react-app: Not Found

Comment: Can you add the version of `node` you're running? `$ node -v`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of struggling with this I updated a whole slew of things on my system.  node, npm, yarn, mocha, and all the packages installed globally with both npm and brew.  This fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently a [bug](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6591) with CRA's tests on new versions of `node`.

Try using the "LTS" (long term support) version of Node:

1. [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/) (choose LTS)
2. [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm): `$ nvm use --lts`.

Then run `$ yarn` again, followed by `$ yarn test`.

---

The issue seems to be with `jest` specifically. The updated version is fixed, but CRA is still in the [process](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/6278) of updating it.

Comment: I ran node -v and get v10.15.3.   I ran yarn test and still just jumps back to cursor.

Comment: Can you confirm that this is a problem with you too?  I've spent two days on this and can't get jest to work no matter how I try to set it up.

Comment: It works for me on LTS. Maybe run “npx create-react-app —info” and paste the result in your question. There are some ideas floated in the issue I linked, such as upgrading jest in a resolution https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/, although your issue doesn’t seem to be exactly the same. Another thing to try is “npm uninstall -g create-react-app” to make sure you are running the latest version, instead of an old global install.

Comment: Starting the development server...

events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

@JBallin -  I got this error when I ran yarn start:      Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached,   any clue?

Comment: Can you make sure you don't have any other terminal/iterm tabs open? May want to try restarting the computer too.

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  After much teeth-gnashing I figured that my npm was all screwed up and did a complete reinstall of node and npm.  So that was fixed.  I'm trying a new CRA now again to see what happens.  ------>  OK, still same thing ... the npm start runs ok.  but the npm test just exits back to cursor with nothing! grrrrr  What can I test separately to break this down?

Comment: Have you tried just following a basic jest tutorial to see if that works?

Comment: Yes I did - same thing happens

Comment: Looking up “jest won’t run”, I’m consistently seeing people say that “watchman” is the issue. They fixed it by uninstalling (and possibly upgrading) watchman. Can you maybe add a list of all of your installed software that could be causing issues? “$ brew list” if using homebrew. Another suggestion I saw was to completely uninstall node, npm, yarn etc and do a fresh install of them.

Comment: I simplified the setup and started new thread  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55191638/jest-doesnt-run-hangs-indefinitely

Comment: Did you try uninstalling watchman, to figure out if that's the issue?