# Jest doesn't run -- hangs indefinitely

Tags: node.js, jestjs, ubuntu-16.04, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I was originally having this problem with create-react-app, so I did really bare bones setup just of jest:

1. created new directory
2. yarn init in that directory
3. yarn add jest
4. created new file sum.js:

   ```
      function sum(a, b) {
         return a + b;
      }
      module.exports = sum;
   ```
5. created file to test above function

   ```
   const sum = require('./sum');

   test('adds 1 + 2 = 3' , () => {
       expect(sum(1,2)).toBe(3);
   });
   ```
6. added to package.json:

   ```
   "scripts": {
   "test": "jest"
   ```

   },

But when I run yarn test, I get this:

```
terry@terry-sharewalker:~/myProjects/test-jest$ yarn jest
yarn run v1.13.0
$ /home/terry/myProjects/test-jest/node_modules/.bin/jest
```

and nothing happens from there.  It just hangs.  The same thing happened with running tests from create-react-app. react-scripts test would show, then nothing.

Here's what I got:

```
Jest "^24.5.0"
Ubuntu 16.04
yarn 1.13.0
watchman 4.9.0
node 10.15.3
```

I've reinstalled and upgraded everything I can think of, including npm, node, watchman, linuxbrew, yarn.  If anybody can help me I'd be forever grateful!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure WHY this worked, but it did.  I reinstalled some global packages on my system:

`npm update npm -g`  (to 6.9.0)

```
npm update -g
```

this updated:
parcel-bundler to 1.12.3

updated watchman:
`brew update watchman`  (to 4.9.0)

Answer (score 17):

I was getting the same issue as well. It can be fixed be updating or reinstalling watchman `brew uninstall watchman` && `brew install watchman`.

More details can be found here https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/4529

Comment: This plus a `brew reinstall watchman` did it for me! ‍♂️

Answer (score 5):

Uninstalling and reinstalling watchman didn't work for me on MacOS

I had to do this:

```sh
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist
watchman version
```

https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/381#issuecomment-257673900

Comment: this did it for me, thank you 

Answer (score 3):

The problem is due to `watchman 4.9`.
Try running `watchman version`, if hangs resolve by running:
`brew reinstall watchman` if you got 4.9, or `brew update watchman` if older.

Ref:
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/4529#issuecomment-333512164